# Mesh shading looks wierd

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, vertices, faces

[image]

Here's the mesh—it doesn't have any doubles or split parts. However, it exhibits this weird reflection regardless of whether it's set to smooth shading or not. This issue has occurred sporadically in version 2.8. I have managed to work around it by deleting and remaking the meshes. Nevertheless, considering that it could become significantly bothersome in the future, I have decided to create a post. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: did you check the orientation of normals and cleared geometry data (if available)?

Comment: as MikoCG says, go into Object Data >Geometry and Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Comment: I did, Recalculated Normals, and there are no nodes for this mesh.

Comment: in that case please try to share your file with https://blend-exchange.com/ and paste it to your question so that we can check it

Comment: uploaded the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:
[image]

Click on Object Data Properties (green reversed triangle) and click on 'Clear custom split normals data'

EDIT: Oh and your normals are probably reversed, use Alt+N to 'recalculate Outside'

Your object now looks as it is supposed to look like:

[image]

(Note: I am using a few addons so you might have less options in that selection)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of recalculating normals : in edit mode, shift+N. You can also toggle smooth shading after the fact : in object mode, right click -> *shade smooth*.